# Cannot await async task

Tags: c#, exception, task

I have a method called `StartAsync` which await different task, this is the design:

```
public async Task StartAsync(int instance)
{
    await SomeController.Foo();
    await AnotherController.Foo2();
}
```

Now I need to run the `StartAsync` method multiple times, so I have created different `Task`, in this way I can manage a single execution of the `Task` of `StartAsync`:

```
Task bot1 = new Task(async () => { await new Bot().StartAsync(1); });

Task bot2 = new Task(async () => { await new Bot().StartAsync(2); });
```

these `Tasks` can be started by the input, essentially, if the user press `1` then the `bot1` Task will start:

```
public async Task<bool> StartBotInstanceAsync(int instance)
{
     try  
     {
          switch(instance)
          {
              case 1:
                  await bot1.Start(); //<- Problem here
                  break;

              case 2:
                  bot2.Start(); 
                  break;
          }

          return true;
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         Logger.Info(ex.ToString());
         return false;
     }
}
```

Essentially I need to write a log when an exception happen in side the try catch block, but for doing this I need to await the `Task` result, unfortunately I get this error:

> Cannot await void

on `await bot1.Start();`

How can I manage the exception in this type of situation?

Comment: `Start` != `StartAsync` - did you mean to write `await bot1.StartAsync();`?

Comment: @Default  `bot1.Start()` is a `Task` which contains `await new Bot().StartAsync(1);`

Comment: You *don't* need cold tasks to make multiple calls. `await` doesn't start a task, it *awaits* an already running tasks. That means you can store the task returned by multiple calls to `Bot.StartAsync` and await them individually or all at once, eg with `await Task.WhenAll(task1,task2);`

Comment: Then, I don't see the `Start` method. Would you mind adding an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: If you could clearly describe what problem you're trying to solve, it would be a start. At the moment, it looks like you're just throwing `await` and `Task` at this problem and just trying to get it to compile without having a clear *spec* for what you're trying to achieve (or if you do have such a spec, you've not shared it with us)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm trying to write the exception generated by the task `bot1, bot2 etc...` inside the `try / catch` block, for doing this I need to await the result because actually the `catch` block isn't firing.

Comment: Do you really need that `switch`? Why not use `var bot=new Bot(); await bot.StartAsync(instance);` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yep, I need it, I have multiple task and I start a `Task` based on the user input

Comment: @JuveMerda you don't need any of that code to catch exceptions. You need to explain what you *actually* want to do though. Why not create a *simple* method that creates a new bot and awaits the task inside a `try/catch`? Do you want to create multiple bot instances, in which case you need a `Bot[]` array?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the application logic is the following: the user write a number in the console, and based on that choice the application start a new  `Task` of the `Bot` class. The method of that class can generate an error, so I need to manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to do it with your current structure then you will need 2 separate statements.

```
case 1:
    bot1.Start();
    await bot1;
    break;
```

Comment: Using cold tasks is the root problem. This only covers it up

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple bot instances, store them in an array and use the `instance` parameter as the index, eg :

```
_bots=new[]{ new Bot(),new Bot()};

public async Task<bool> StartBotInstanceAsync(int instance)
{
     try  
     {
          await _bots[instance-1].StartAsync();
          return true;
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         Logger.Info(ex.ToString());
         return false;
     }
}
```

Or even better :

```
public async Task<bool> StartBotInstanceAsync(Bot bot)
{
     try  
     {
          await bot.StartAsync();
          return true;
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         Logger.Info(ex.ToString());
         return false;
     }
}

var myBot=_bots[instance-1];
var started=await StartBotInstanceAsync(myBot);
```

More complex flows can be created easily by using `async` functions that take the bot as a parameter, eg :

```
public async Task SomeComplexFlow(Bot bot)
{
    try
    {
        await bot.StartAsync();
        await bot.DoSomething();
        ...
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        ...
    }
}


var myBot=_bots[instance-1];
await SomeComplexFlow(myBot);
```

It's possible to await multiple tasks for completion too. One coud use `Task.WhenAll` to wait for all bots to terminate, eg :

```
await Task.WhenAll(_bots[0].StopAsync()...);
```

Or, better yet :

```
var tasks=_bots.Select(bot=>bot.StopAsync());
await Tasks.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Thanks for the array advice, I implemented your solution based on your comment already and the only problem is that if I add this inside the `SomeComplexFlow` => `throw new Exception("An error happened!");` I don't get the breakpoint firing in the `catch` block, why?